Unable to get Functions Created successfully in AWS RDS Instance running PostgreSQL 16.3
I have been trying to get Functions created successfully in my AWS RDS Instance running PostgresSQL 16.3. I keep getting the same types of errors. "$$" is causing the errors,  and can't figure out the correct syntax. I have created a local instance of PostgreSQL and get the same errors. The syntax is the correct one on the PostgreSQL website. I have enclosed the code and the error.:
Code:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_current_user_id()
    RETURNS uuid
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
   AS 
$$
    SELECT current_setting('app.current_user_id', true)::uuid;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.user_has_role(p_role_names text[])
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM public.um_user_roles ur
        JOIN public.um_roles r ON ur.role_id = r.id
        WHERE ur.user_id = public.get_current_user_id()
        AND r.role_name = ANY(p_role_names)
        AND ur.status = 'active'
        AND (ur.valid_until IS NULL OR ur.valid_until > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    );
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

Error:
Error at line 37:
Statement: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_current_user_id() RETURNS uuid LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ DECLARE BEGIN RETURN current_setting('app.current_user_id', true)::uuid;
Error message: unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$ DECLARE BEGIN RETURN current_setting('app.current_user_id', true)::uuid;"
LINE 1: ...urrent_user_id() RETURNS uuid LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ DECLARE...
                                                             ^


The error message is inconsistent with the code that was posted. The body of get_current_user_id is not valid for a plpgsql function (try declaring LANGUAGE sql instead. The only syntactic problem with the second function is that LANGUAGE plpgsql is declared both at the top and bottom.

The issue is with the dollar signs.I always get a air with the dollar signs.And I don't know another way to do the function

The error message didn't come from the posted code (the statement text in the error message doesn't appear anywhere in the posted code). Please update the post with the actual code that resulted in the exception. My previous comment correctly identifies the syntactic issues with the posted code.
